# failed to connect sql server 2005 and php grid with odbc

Tags: php, sql-server-2005, jqgrid, odbc

I have made a connection between sql server 2005 and php using odbc and it works perfectly.

My problem is that when I tried to connect sql server 2005 and php grid, it occurs an error that says:

```
Error: Could not connect to the database
```

The only thing I did is that I set the connection in conf.php which looks like this:

```
define('DB_HOSTNAME','dbhostname'); // database host name
define('DB_USERNAME', 'dbusername');     // database user name
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpassword'); // database password
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname'); // database name     
define('DB_TYPE', 'odbc_mssql');  // database type
define('DB_CHARSET','');

define('SERVER_ROOT', '/phpGrid');

require_once('phpGrid.php');
```

Is there something I need to change in other files or what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i cannot add a comment and sorry for my english.

Is your 'dbhostname' the name of your odbc connection (might be different from the sql server instance name)?

Proof if your conf.php and your php file you use to display the grid are in utf8 without BOM encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection settings again. If you use [Guriddo Suito PHP Grid](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102675) then you can look at this documentation [here](http://trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v20bnptk.htm) and [here](http://trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v20f82ru.htm)